# Scrapy [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (301)

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler, http-status-code-301

I'm getting this error while scraping the web with Scrapy, and I've looked through all sorts of 301 errors on the site, tried the solutions as well, but it's still not fixed. Usually everyone gets redirect error but I guess this is different and I still can't figure it out please help.

Before the 301 error, I was also getting the 429 error. I think this error was due to too many requests in one minute and I solved it by making `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 16` and `DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 1`. But I couldn't get rid of the 301 error.

**setting.py**

```
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 16
DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 1
HTTPERROR_ALLOWED_CODES = [301]
```

**spider.py**

```
class EmlakSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    handle_httpstatus_list = [301,302]
    name = 'emlak'
    allowed_domains = ['www.hepsiemlak.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.hepsiemlak.com/satilik-sahibinden']
    headers= {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:105.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/105.0'}
    base_url = 'https://www.hepsiemlak.com/satilik-sahibinden'

    def parse(self, response):
        ads = response.css('li.listing-item a.img-link::attr(href)').getall()
        for ad in ads:
            yield Request(url=self.base_url+ad, headers=self.headers, meta = {'dont_redirect': True,'handle_httpstatus_list': [301,302]}, callback=self.parse_ad)
        
        next_page = "https://www.hepsiemlak.com"+response.css('div.he-pagination a.he-pagination__navigate-text.he-pagination__navigate-text--next::attr(href)').get()
        if next_page is not None:
            yield Request(next_page, headers=self.headers, meta = {'dont_redirect': True,'handle_httpstatus_list': [301,302]}, callback=self.parse)
    
    def parse_ad(self, response):
        try:
            yield {
                'Province': response.css('div.det-title-bottom li::text').get().strip(),
                'District': response.css('div.det-title-bottom li::text')[1].get().strip(),
                'Full Name': response.css('div.owner-header.clearfix div.owner-firm-name::text').get().strip(),
                'From': response.css('div.owner-header.clearfix span.owner-member-type.mr10::text').get(),
                'Page No': response.request.url[-1]
            }
        except:
           pass
```

**scrapy crawl -s USER_AGENT='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:105.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/105.0' emlak -o ilanlar.csv**
[image]

Comment: it's protected by cloudflare....

Comment: :( Is there any solution for this situation? I mean this is not about my code or my method right?

Comment: There are solutions, but this isn't something scrapy on it''s own will be enough to scrape

Comment: What's your advice?

Comment: you can try using selenium or playwright....

Comment: Doesn't the redirected request go to the intended page? When you set the 301, and 302 in `handle_httpstatus_list`, the redirection won't occur.